# Moq error "Moq expected invocation once, but was 0times", Pass in one test case but fails at other, though the endpoint works fine

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core, moq, xunit

I have a similar test for two endpoints (Get and Post), which verifies if the service is being called when the endpoint is hit.
The Moq itself is failing but the endpoint works fine, thus I don't know what to do to make the test pass.

```
[HttpPost("api")]
public async Task<IActionResult> PostVenda(PostVendaRequestModel postRequest) {
    Venda postVenda = await _vendaService.PostVendaService(
        vendedor: postRequest.vendedor, 
        carrinho: postRequest.carrinho);

    return Ok(postVenda);
}
```

The Get test itself pass normally.

```
[Fact]
public async Task Get_OnSuccess_InvokesVendaServiceOnce() {
    //Arrange
    var mockVendaService = new Mock<IVendaService>();
    
    mockVendaService
        .Setup(service => service.GetVendaByIdService(1))
        .ReturnsAsync(new Venda());
                                                            
    var sut = new VendaController(mockVendaService.Object);

    //Act
    var result = await sut.GetVendaById(1);

    //Assert
    mockVendaService.Verify(
        service => service.GetVendaByIdService(1), 
        Times.Once()
    );
}
```

But the test for the Post method itself keeps on failing.

```
[Fact]
public async Task Post_Venda_OnSuccess_InvokesVendaServiceOnce() {
    //Arrange
    var mockVendaService = new Mock<IVendaService>();
    VendaController.PostVendaRequestModel newVenda = new VendaController.PostVendaRequestModel() { 
        carrinho = CarrinhoFixture.Carrinho, 
        vendedor = VendedorFixture.Vendedor 
    };

    mockVendaService
        .Setup(service => service.PostVendaService(VendedorFixture.Vendedor, CarrinhoFixture.Carrinho))
        .ReturnsAsync(new Venda());

    var sut = new VendaController(mockVendaService.Object);


    //Act
    var result = await sut.PostVenda(new VendaController.PostVendaRequestModel());

    //Assert
    mockVendaService.Verify(
        service => service.PostVendaService(VendedorFixture.Vendedor, CarrinhoFixture.Carrinho), 
        Times.Once);
}
```

My service itself isn't complex and works fine when the two endpoints use the two method.

```
public class VendaService : IVendaService {
    public List<Venda> _vendas;

    public VendaService() {
        this._vendas = VendasFixture.Vendas;
    }
    public async Task<Venda> GetVendaByIdService(int id) {
        List<Venda> vendaSearch = _vendas.Where(v => v.VendaId == id).ToList();
        if(vendaSearch.Count == 0) 
            return null;

        return vendaSearch[0];
    }

    public async Task<Venda> PostVendaService(Vendedor vendedor, List<Item> carrinho) {
        Venda venda = new Venda() {
            VendaId = 1,
            Vendedor = vendedor,
            Carrinho = carrinho,
            DataDaVenda = DateTime.Now,
            Status = Enums.Status.AguardandoPagamento
        };
        VendasFixture.Vendas.Add(venda);
        return venda;
    }
}
```

Working with:

1. .Net Core 6.0.402

Packages:

1. Moq 4.18.2
2. FluentAssertions 6.7.0
3. xunit 2.4.1

Comment: You create `newVenda` but never use it, instead passing a new `VendaController.PostVendaRequestModel()`, meaning that the call is probably actually to `PostVendaService(null, null)`. Didn't you find this out when you stepped through the unit test with the debugger?

Comment: Year, I forgot to delete that part of the code, shouldn't be needed for this test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Option 1

Either perform the act like this as [ProgrammingLlama](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3181933/programmingllama) has suggested

```
var result = await sut.PostVenda(newVenda);
```

because your `Setup` and `Verify` calls were defined with the following arguments: `VendedorFixture.Vendedor`, `CarrinhoFixture.Carrinho`.

If you pass `new VendaController.PostVendaRequestModel()` to the `sut.PostVenda` then your mock will return with `null` (that's the default behaviour) instead of `new Venda()` because the parameters were not matching.

#### Option 2

Or do the arrange like this

```
mockVendaService
        .Setup(service => service.PostVendaService(It.IsAny<Vendedor>(), It.IsAny<ist<Item>>()))
        .ReturnsAsync(new Venda());
```

and the assert like that

```
mockVendaService.Verify(
        service => service.PostVendaService(It.IsAny<Vendedor>(), It.IsAny<ist<Item>>()), 
        Times.Once);
```

Here your mock can accept any parameter. It does not matter that you call the `sut.PostVenda` with `newVenda` or with `new VendaController.PostVendaRequestModel()`, it will always return with a new `Venda`.